# Unity Watson SDK error on Speech to Text Example

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I'm trying to run the newest Unity Watson SDK from GitHub. Whenever I try to play the example scene for speech to text, I get this error. I have the API key set and my region is US-Dallas, but I don't think it's related to the problem.

I'm building an app for Android that utilizes speech to text. I've tried looking this up for hours, but I can't find a solution. I've tried re-downloading the SDK but nothing changed.

```
[02/03/2019 00:54:42][Unity][CRITICAL] Unity Exception 
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.

Parameter name: length : System.String.Substring (System.Int32                                                 
startIndex, System.Int32 length) (at         
<f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Connection.RESTConnector.AddHeaders 
(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] headers) 
(at Assets/unity-sdk- 
 2.14.0/Scripts/Connection/RESTConnector.cs:380)
 IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Connection.RESTConnector+ 
 <ProcessRequestQueue>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/unity-sdk- 
 2.14.0/Scripts/Connection/RESTConnector.cs:470)
 IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Utilities.Runnable+Routine.MoveNext () 
 (at Assets/unity-sdk-2.14.0/Scripts/Utilities/Runnable.cs:131)
 UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext 
(System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr 
returnValueAddress) 
(at 
/Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Debug.DebugReactor:ProcessLog(LogRecord) 
(at Assets/unity-sdk-2.14.0/Scripts/Debug/DebugReactor.cs:60)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging.LogSystem:ProcessLog(LogRecord) 
(at Assets/unity-sdk-2.14.0/Scripts/Logging/Logger.cs:206)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging.Log:Critical(String, String, 
Object[]) (at Assets/unity-sdk-2.14.0/Scripts/Logging/Logger.cs:294)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging.LogSystem:UnityLogCallback(String, 
String, LogType) (at Assets/unity-sdk- 
2.14.0/Scripts/Logging/Logger.cs:167)
UnityEngine.Application:CallLogCallback(String, String, LogType, 
Boolean)
```

I know the scene is supposed to output what it thinks I am saying, but nothing is happening. Any help would be appreciated!